# How do i enable a timed laptop screen power off from the console?

Tags: server, power-management, laptop

I have logind.conf set with `handlelidswitch=ignore` etc..., this is working great.  But the screen stays on permenantly as the system never sleeps.

How do i switch off the built in laptop monitor after x minutes or when the lid closes (or both).

`cat /sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank` returns 0 as expected.

I think i need to `setterm --blank 30 --powerdown 2` where blank is in seconds and powerdown is in minutes.

Where is best to add this for initialising, I thought /etc/rc.local, but this is systemd, and now i'm confused.

Rather not screw this up, and i don't really know what i'm doing, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I gave this a go and succeeded.

As per [systemd man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man5/systemd.service.5.html) I've created a service in/etc/system/systemd/

Used [setterm man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/setterm.1.html) for the variables --blank 2 --powerdown 3

`[Unit]
Description=Enable virtual console blanking and poweroff

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=TERM=linux
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/console
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm --blank 2 --powerdown 3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`

saved as enable-console-blanking.service

Run `sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/enable-console-blanking.service` 
then `systemctl started` and `systemctl enabled` it so `systemctl status` shows me:

```
> ● enable-console-blanking.service - Enable virtual console blanking
> and poweroff
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/enable-console-blanking.service; enabled; vendor
> preset: enabled)
>      Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2020-04-19 00:16:25 BST; 2s ago
>     Process: 20573 ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm --blank 2 --powerdown 3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)    Main PID: 20573 (code=exited,
> status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I think thats 2 mins blank and 3 mins powersave, cant quite figure out what its doing, but it is going off, and thats a win in my books.

Comment: For anyone searching this this isnt quite the answer because this stopped something loading boot, so beware follwing this!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I hope it may still help someone.

Setterm *should* work, but is hard to get working right in my experience (see e.g. the comment on the other answer about it stopping boot working).
It needs to run at boot, but it also needs to run on an actual tty for it to work.
I prefer the kernel parameter solution.

## Kernel boot parameter: `consoleblank`

Linux has a boot parameter `consoleblank=XX` which powers off the tty after XX seconds.

To use this parameter:

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`
- Find the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="foo=bar"`
- Add the parameter: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="consoleblank=60 foo=bar"`
- Run `update-grub`
- Reboot

With this, the display should turn off after one minute (adjust the number if this is too short for you). This will work both on the login prompt, and when someone is logged in.

This won't affect Wayland. Not sure about classic Xorg.