# Boot splash persists at login, so power saving and screen blanking don't come into effect?

Tags: boot, login

I have disabled gdm3 automatically loading at startup.

Now from a cold boot the boot splash image (dell in this case see image) persists.  The laptop is active and I can SSH in. I can enter console as normal and then login.

How do I finish booting into console awaiting login?  This is stopping the laptop blanking the screen and entering display power-save mode.

**Edit:**
Actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd> etc don't open TTY1 either, I've broken something at startup it appears, but I am still able to SSH in.

[image]

`journalctl -b` returns this at the end which stands out to me

`Apr 19 19:54:29 alex-docker-server sudo[5359]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Apr 19 19:54:34 alex-docker-server systemd[5068]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Apr 19 19:54:37 alex-docker-server sudo[5359]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Apr 19 19:54:37 alex-docker-server sudo[5359]: alexdodd : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/alexdodd ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status enable-console-blanking.service
Apr 19 19:54:37 alex-docker-server sudo[5359]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by alexdodd(uid=0)
Apr 19 19:54:37 alex-docker-server sudo[5359]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root`

Here is the full boot log if anyone can point me in the direction of where I should investigate: https://paste.ee/p/oiDxG

Comment: Re-enable gdm3, and then tell us what your ORIGINAL problem was. BTW... it looks like you've got a defective LCD display panel.

Comment: I disabled it with `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Do you want me to enable it with `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

The laptop hasn't used a gui from the beginning.  Its desktop install with gui autostart disabled.

I have recently tweaked the blank and powerdown values with setterm and added that as a service.  See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228271/how-do-i-enable-a-timed-laptop-screen-power-off-from-the-console

So it could be that, but it was working yesterday.

Ha, the LCD is defective, this will be a headless test environment.

Comment: I'm sorry. It looks like you've hacked your system too much, so I can't help you, other than suggest you do a fresh install, and then ask for help if you need it.

Comment: Seems a bit extreme to have to fresh install when everything works whilst im SSH'ed and all services I want still run!

Comment: You've disabled gdm3, you've written system .services, you've chmod'd parts of your system, you're getting PAM errors and "/etc/securetty: No such file or directory" errors. How are we supposed to support this?

Comment: Everything i've done is in your comment and that other linked question!  But I get your point.  I'll search plod away myself for a bit.  It's to do with my last question (can you help with that, is what I did right/wrong there?). This only happened after a reboot overnight since that.  Boot.log is here (https://paste.ee/p/oiDxG) just in case you have any ideas, no worries otherwise :)  Something has tied the console up on boot that doesnt let it release to show login. *I think.